# JavaScript countdown

Tags: javascript, html

Why wont it countdown?

```
<script language="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
var container = document.getElementById('dl');
var seconds = 10;
var timer;
function countdown() {
seconds--;
if(seconds > 0) {
    container.innerHTML = 'Please wait <b>'+seconds+'</b> seconds..';
} else {
    container.innerHTML = '<a href="download.php">Download</a>';
    clearInterval(timer);
}
}
timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
</script>

<div id="dl"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="setInterval(countdown, 1000);" id="dl" value="Download" />
```

Comment: If you click the button, you generate a **second** countdown operating on the same value. This will generate unexpected behavior. You should remove this line: `timer = setInterval...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move the `<script>` block **after** the `<div id="dl"></div>`.

This way, when `document.getElementById('dl');` is executed, the corresponding element in the page will already exist.

With what you posted, when `document.getElementById('dl');` is executed, the corresponding `<div>` is not there yet -- and, so, cannot be found.

Comment: or wrap it in a callback that runs on page loaded, e.g., in jQuery `$(function() { ...your code here });`

Comment: That would probably be a better solution, yes -- and it would allow things not have *local* variables, to no pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to reach the element before it exists, as the code runs before the element is loaded.

Move the line that locates the element inside the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var seconds = 10;
var timer;

function countdown() {
  var container = document.getElementById('dl');
  seconds--;
  if(seconds > 0) {
    container.innerHTML = 'Please wait <b>'+seconds+'</b> seconds..';
  } else {
    container.innerHTML = '<a href="download.php">Download</a>';
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

</script>

<div id="dl"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="setInterval(countdown, 1000);" id="dl" value="Download" />
```

Answer (score -2):

The `setInterval` takes a string to execute, not a function pointer.

```
timer = setInterval("countdown()", 1000);
```

Comment: This is wrong.  You *can* pass a string, but it's not considered a good idea. You can definitely pass a function pointer.